# Change the folder location for Angular ui-bootstrap templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I am trying to use ui-bootstrap.min.js with the external templates.

The error I am getting is:

```
http://localhost:13132/Place/template/timepicker/timepicker.html 404 (Not Found)
```

I would like for every page, for every template, it to look for my templates under:

```
http://localhost:13132/js/app/template/...
```

but I cannot seem to find where I could change the location where this is pointing to.

Anyone know how to make this change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [this issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/743) on github, the templateUrl is not configurable. You could change the templateUrl property in each directive definition

```
.directive('accordion', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'EA',
        controller:'AccordionController',
        transclude: true,
        replace: false,
        templateUrl: 'template/accordion/accordion.html'
 };
```

but that would be brittle and hard to maintain. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like they're going to make this configurable - but the thread is an interesting read.

Answer (score 3):

This can be handled using `$provide.decorator`

Read more about this issue:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/743

```
myApp.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('datepickerDirective', function($delegate) {
    //array of datepicker directives
    $delegate[0].templateUrl = "my/datepicker.html";
    return $delegate;
  });
});
```

**Update:** I've tested this solution and it does work for other templates as well, and only requires those small changes to app.js. I've tested this now with timepicker.html and day.html, defining a decorator for timepickerDirective and daypickerDirective. The latter is used to override the calendar table display. The templateUrl path is relative to your app folder, in my case it was *"partials/fragments/day.html"*.

Comment: Can you provide a demo of this?. I'm trying to implement this solution but I'm not getting any luck

Comment: This is how I'm adding a prefix for a set the template URLs (more than 1 directive): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4f44af87dead48ba05bd. It doesn't look like the best solution though

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative without changing code is to add some sort of virtual server directory that maps `/Place/template` to your actual location of `/js/app/template/`

The implementation of virtual directories is obviously in your server platform of choice.